# Adding a logo to a data structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uiimage

I have a tableviewcell that has an UIImage for a team logo, I'm getting my data, as team name, points, etc, from a third party XML feed, which does not have the logo data included.

So I need to add this info to that data.

The problem is that i do not know how to do that.

I have my parseXML method which works, everything is working, but my uiimage for logo is being populated by a hard coded array that has all the .png files, the only thing is that if team in number1 place drops to number2, the logos won't update.

Please see my code below, I have included my logos array and the xml data structure after being parsed.

Can anyone provide a sample code of how I can achieve a solution to my problem? I've been stuck in here for a while.

```
-(void) parseXML{

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"apikeygoeshere"]];

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *xml = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlString];

    NSMutableArray *items = [xml objectForKey:@"TeamLeagueStanding"];

    NSString *nullentry = @""; // custom code for specific reason
    NSString *nullentry2 = @""; // custom code for a specific reason

    [items insertObject:nullentry atIndex:0]; // custom code for a specific reason
    [items insertObject:nullentry2 atIndex:1]; // custom code for a specific reason

    [self setTableData:items];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StandingsIdent";
    StandingsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

     NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

    long row = [indexPath row];

    cell.cellTeamName.text = [item objectForKey:@"Team"];;
    cell.cellTeamLogo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_teamLogos[row]];
    cell.cellTeamPosition.text = _teamPosition[row];
    cell.cellPlayed.text = [item objectForKey:@"Played"];
    cell.cellWins.text = [item objectForKey:@"Won"]; 
    cell.cellTies.text = [item objectForKey:@"Draw"]; 
    cell.cellLoses.text = [item objectForKey:@"Lost"]; ;
    cell.cellPoints.text = [item objectForKey:@"Points"]; 
    cell.cellInfo.text = _infoLeague[row];

    }

 else {

    }
 }

 LOGO ARRAY

     _teamLogos = @[@"",
                   @"",
                   @"1478.png",
                   @"1487.png",
                   @"1489.png",
                   @"1494.png",
                   @"1474.png",
                   @"2390.png",
                   @"2433.png",
                   @"1488.png",
                   @"1481.png",
                   @"2383.png",
                   @"1476.png",
                   @"1495.png",
                   @"729500.png",
                   @"2386.png",
                   @"2445.png",
                   @"2393.png",
                   @""];


XML DATA STRUCTURE AFTER BEING PARSED

Draw = 10;
"Goal_Difference" = "-17";
"Goals_Against" = 39;
"Goals_For" = 22;
Lost = 11;
NumberOfShots = 395;
Played = 25;
PlayedAtHome = 13;
PlayedAway = 12;
Points = 22;
RedCards = 5;
Team = Partick;
"Team_Id" = 561;
Won = 4;
YellowCards = 41;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the exact problem is.  Can you clarify exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's getting confusing what are you actually up to. It seems you are correctly populating your table cells only if `item` is a NSDictionary but returning nothing afterwards! It should cause problems. Can you please point out your exact problem?

Comment: I want to associate a logo to a specific team name... lets say... if the team name is Cubs, then uiimage should be cubs.png

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your hard coded image names in an array, simply name the images the same as the team name or better yet the team id.

Then you can do:

```
cell.cellTeamLogo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:item[@"Team_Id"]];
```

This keeps things nice and simple. If you add a new team you simply add a new image with the same team id (with the `.png` extension added).

Comment: can you provide a sample code, your solution seems pretty easy, but i'm not sure how it will be added to my data structure.

Comment: I showed the important code. Just make sure you include the `Team_Id` in you XML parsing and data structure. And then rename your images to match the team ids. Get rid of your `_teamLogos` array. You don't need anything to track the images.

Comment: yea but thats exactly my question how do i include that? it's my first app some things are still blurry to me :P

Comment: You have code to get the `Team`, `Played`, `Won` and the other fields, right? Add similar code to also get the `Team_Id` field.